# A Batch script to call virustotal api and add a windows firewall rule if a baddie is detected?

Tags: security, batch-file, anti-virus

Basically, when I connect to any site, it loads not only stuff on that server, but also stuff like background images, scripts, icons, fonts from third party sites. I was wondering if it would be possible to run a virustotal check and block the baddies prior I download them or my browser loads them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. You can ask programming questions on [so] and home computing questions on [su].

Comment: You can give a try with this extension [VT4Browsers](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/vt4browsers/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this extension [VT4Browsers](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/vt4browsers/)

Scan your downloads with VirusTotal before storing them, free and easy

[image]